# Get hostname of a RDP client computer

Tags: windows, command-line, remote-desktop

I have a question which I'm sure has a simple solution, but it keeps eluding me.

There's a server in the picture that is used by several people.
All of them use the same account to log in.
The only way to differentiate sessions would be by hostname or IP.

So - How to see, on the remote computer, a hostname of the client connected?

For example, I RDP in to the server `256.12.13.1` from my IP `256.12.13.7`.
Is there a command I could run on the server in that remote session that will output `256.12.13.7`?

I ask because it would be good if that command would output `256.12.13.9` when person connects from that other IP.

So I can put it in startup and whenever someone connects script like this would run:

```
gethostname >> rdplog.txt<br>
date /t >> rdplog.txt <br>
time /t >> rdplog.txt
```

So this can basically equal to a very simple login log.

Comment: I'm looking into powershell now. I guess that's my only option left.

Comment: Obviously, few people can dictate how a business uses IT resources, but may I suggest that multiple people using the same login is extremely poor security practice? If you are in the position to improve this system, I would recommend it.

Comment: @MyrddinEmrys, You are absolutely correct. But no, I can not make the change in the system as it is now, I did try already :) However, it's a LAN environment and people do not store much important data so it is okay. The only thing I am concerned about is data corruption, but this is where backup kicks in ;) Thank you for your thoughts though, much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could write a batch script like:

```
netstat -na | find "3389" | find "ESTABLISHED" >> C:\path_to_rdplog.txt
date /T >> C:\path_to_rdplog.txt
time /T >> C:\path_to_rdplog.txt
echo. >> C:\path_to_rdplog.txt
echo ----------- >> C:\path_to_rdplog.txt
echo. >> C:\path_to_rdplog.txt
```

You just have to make sure that the person who's logging in has write permissions to C:\path_to_rdplog.txt

Comment: Exactly what I needed! How could I have made such an oversight? netstat! Thank you matrixx333, you just made my day. Of course, I edited the script a bit more to suit my needs better, but you made a hell of a job sir. Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: Glad I could help you out @extremko!

Comment: Though I suspect this wouldn’t give the right answer when multiple clients are connected and you want to discover the client connected to the *currently active* session.

Answer (score 3):

A very old thread but anyway. We used to check an environment variable CLIENTNAME that is set in the RDP session. We had an older application that could not easily use windows API's or Powershell and checked this environment variable. This variable holds the hostname of the client machine making the RDP connection.

Comment: I appreciate the update, even with the thread being old. Clientname variable would certainly resolve my issue back then! Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft MVP Shay Levy made a [`PSTerminalServices`](https://psterminalservices.codeplex.com/) PowerShell module that has Terminal Services cmdlets.

It needs to be installed, it is not there by default.

I have not used it yet, I just found it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Haven't tried it, but will :)

Answer (score 2):

A new Powershell answer to a rather old question

```
(Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational';ID=1149;StartTime=(Get-Date).AddDays(-31);} | ForEach-Object {[PSCustomObject] @{User=$_.Properties[0].Value;ClientName=$_.Properties[1].Value;IPAddress=$_.Properties[2].Value; TimeCreated=$_.TimeCreated;}} | Where-Object User -eq $env:USERNAME | Sort-Object -Property TimeCreated -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).ClientName
```

The snippet grabs all the events from the event log for Terminal Services over the past 31 days and builds custom objects with the user name, the client name, the ip address and the timestamp of the logon entry. It then filters the custom objects using the name of the current user and then sorts the custom objects in descending order of login date and finally grabs the top most (i.e. most recent event log entry), and extracts the Client Name from the custom object. I am literally walking thru the code and explaining each piece of code sequentially - there really is not a whole lot to the code.

What is important to note is that the event log has a record of successful RDP connections with the data of interest to us. Parsing, filtering, sorting, and extracting the relevant data to turn it into useful information is the name of the game!

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining it.